# URL redirection

Tags: drupal, redirect, migration

I am trying to migrate an asp.net website into Drupal. Unfortunately the content on the website contains a lot of links that are hardcoded.

Is there a way to redirect these links to the new nodes in Drupal.

Answer (score 4):

The [path_redirect](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) module will help you with that (drupal 6).

Note that the project has moved to http://drupal.org/project/redirect for Drupal 7.

Comment: Also .htaccess redirections help to you, it will more faster, but less "setuppable".